# IText 7 with C# acroforms flattening problem when working with RTL

Tags: c#, pdf, itext, itext7

I am using IText 7 with C# to fill "acroForms" programmatically.
I found how to do it when dealing with RTL languages.

The problem occurs when I need to disable (flatten) an input field , the value disappears.

When I use LTR (English) the values are disabled - flattened and everything works well.

The code:

```
PdfDocument pdf = new PdfDocument(new PdfReader(@"C:\test\test.pdf"), new PdfWriter(@"C:\test\test2.pdf"));
PdfAcroForm form = PdfAcroForm.GetAcroForm(pdf, true);
form.SetNeedAppearances(true);
IDictionary<String, PdfFormField> fields = form.GetFormFields();
PdfFormField toSet;
fields.TryGetValue("CM@SHEM_PRATI@1", out toSet);
toSet.SetValue("גגג");
form.PartialFormFlattening("CM@SHEM_PRATI@1");
form.FlattenFields();
pdf.Close();
```

Do I miss a configuration for flattening RTL inserted fields?
Is there another way to disable input fields with C# Itext 7?

Comment: Have you checked whether the font in the Form field definition in your pdf does support those RTL glyphs? Pdf viewers may use own replacement fonts when filling in but not all pdf processors necessarily do. Furthermore, depending on the script in question, the calligraphy add-on may be required.

Comment: Yes it does. I understood that in order to  use PdfCalligraph, I need the typography module. This module won't work without an official license key.
I work with atrial version, because I don't know yet if IText will suit our needs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was solved.
I added the itext7.pdfcalligraph add-on.
Then added an rtl font to the code above:

```
PdfFont heb = PdfFontFactory.CreateFont(@"/path/to/font.ttf", "Identity-H", true);
toSet.SetFont(heb);
```

The input field flattened and the value still could be seen.